# In a situation where אמירה לעכו"ם is permitted, how can one be sure that the person he is talking to is truly a Goy

Tags: shabbat, gentiles, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, kol-kavuah

In a situation where אמירה לעכו"ם (telling a non-Jew to do something for a Jew, which the Jew is forbidden to do) is permitted, if a person goes to a non Jew and asks him to do it, how can he be sure that the person he is talking to is truly a Goy? As long as there is even one Jew that lives in a fixed dwelling in that city (who looks like a non Jew), every person should be a questionable Jew because of *Kol Kavuah Kemechtza al mechtza*?

See [HERE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62670/logic-behind-kol-kavua-kmechtza-al-mechtze) for explanation of the term "*Kol Kavuah Kemechtza al mechtza*"

Comment: You ask him this question, and if (s)he is truly confused, (s)he is not a Jew! :-D

Comment: @Kazibácsi Something hinted that you were going to suggest something like this. Reality is, it's sometimes amazing that "ignorant" Gentiles sometimes know more about a subject than *Talmidei Chachamim*. These days, it seems that the definition of *am ha'aretz* may need to revert back to its original definition!

Comment: @DanF I don't know precisely these _halakhot,_ but can't you ask this person, whether (s)he was a Jew?

Comment: I think that the only sure way to know is to inquire who is mother was. Of course, it's possible that his mom may have also been Jewish and not known that. If you want to have some certainty, you can, perhaps, delve back 3 or 4 generations. If they're all McClure's, etc., chances are going back 3 or 4 generations may provide consistency.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Of course you can ask. But, many people are Jewish and don't know it. (Chaba"d seems pretty decent at discovering this from people. I don't know how they do it.) See previous comment. I think that method should provide more clarity. It's not perfect, but, I think, more reliable. Seriously, how could one know 100%, anyway?

Comment: @DanF Then let's ask Chabad to find it out! :-)
Indeed, many non-Jews think about this 50% rule, while we only consider the mothers.

Comment: I think you’re really confused as to the application of Kol Kavu’a. You’ve asked an awful lot of questions lately based on this principle, while most of these questions are answered by “Kol Kavu’a doesn’t apply. This is a classic case of Rov.” I think a better question to ask is “When do we apply Kol Kavu’a?” and all of these will fall into place.

Comment: @DonielF Re. "This is a classic case of Rov" - Do you mean "bitul b'Rov"? - If you do I strongly advise that you review your sources. Bitul B'rov totally does not apply here! we aren't dealing with a question of Taaruvos. If you meant "Kol Deporish Meruba Porish", obviously  the rule of Kol Deporish Meruba Porish cannot apply because the website is not porish, so what we end up with is, albeit not a very "classic case", yet a case nonetheless of  kol kavuah kemechtza al mechtza.

Comment: I strongly advise that you review what question we’re discussing here - we’re talking about whether a person is Jewish or not, nothing to do with your website question. Yes, I meant Kol deParish. When I say classic case, I mean that in the sugya of Kol deParish this very question is one of the ones discussed in the classic sources (I’ll try to get an actual source later B”N).

Comment: Maybe a factor could be because it's deRabannan

Comment: @DonielF Of course it would be one of the ones discussed in the classic sources of kol D'porish if the person came to us and we had to decide if he's a jew or a goy, but I was talking about when you go to the person to ask him to do something for you, HE IS KAVUAH not porish.

Comment: A formerly religious Jew that I know, was walking in a predominantly Jewןsh neighborhood. Externally, he looks like a non-Jew. Someone stopped him in the street on Shabbos, and asked him to do some melacha for him. He answered him back in Yiddish, and said to him, "און וואס איז מיט אמירה לעכו"ם?"

Answer (score 1):

*Maseches Kesubos* 15b says we can go after the majority of types of people in the city. So if most of the population is Gentile, in a case where someone who looks gentile is found in the street he can be a Shabbos Goy as we follow the Majority:

> מצא בה תינוק מושלך אם רוב עובדי כוכבים עובד כוכבי' אם רוב ישראל ישראל מחצה על מחצה ישראל

Even if the Gentile is in his house in a City of mostly Jews, if you ask him "are you Jewish" and he says "no" you can rely on him as a Shabbos Goy. this is because Most people who say they are not Jewish are genuinely not Jewish this is רוב- Majority. We are not worried about the minority who are Jewish and pretending to be Gentiles (whom we cannot ask to break Shabbos) because they are NOT *Kavua* as *Tosfos Nazir* 12a explains:

> לא אמרינן קבוע כמחצה דמי אלא כשהאיסור ניכר לעצמו וההיתר ניכר לעצמו אבל כשאין האיסור ניכר לעצמו לא אמרינן קבוע
>   We do not say "Someone fixed is like 50/50" in a case where we cannot specifically locate the fixed person (i.e we cannot pinpoint where these self denying Jews homes are)"

So, since someone hiding his Jewishness is not *Kavua* as he cannot be located, we can rely that the person being asked to do a *Melacha* (CYLOR only specific Melachos are permitted by a Goy) if he/she says he/she is a Gentile  based on "majority"(i.e majority of people who say they aren't Jewish are not Jewish).